# Injecting Laravel 5.1 "Illuminate\Http\Request" in your custom classes?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here is my simple **App\Libraries\Gelocation.php** class,

```
namespace App\Libraries;

use Location;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GeoLocation
{
    public function getLocationByIP($ip = null)
    {
        // If IP address is set
        if ($ip) {
            $location = Location::get($ip);
        } else {
            $location = Location::get();
        }

        // Get the location by city
        return $location->cityName;
    }

    public function getLocationByCoordinates($longitute, $latitude)
    {
        //
    }

    public function getLocation(Request $request)
    {
        // Check if the location is already set in the cookie
        if ($request->cookie('location')) {
            return $request->cookie('location');
        } else {
            $location = $this->getLocationByIP();

            // Set location in the cookie
            $request->cookie()->forever('location', $location);

            return $location;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this class in my **PagesController.php** controller as follows,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\GeoLocation;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public $location;

    public function __construct(GeoLocation $location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        dd($this->location->getLocation());
        return view('pages.index');
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code I get this error,

> ErrorException in GeoLocation.php line 28:
>
> Argument 1 passed to App\Libraries\GeoLocation::getLocation() must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given, called in
>   /var/www/blogs/app/Http/Controllers/PagesController.php on line 22 and
>   defined

Comment: Have you tried this? ` dd($this->location->getLocation(new \Illuminate\Http\Request())` also dig into the geolocation documentation for possible arguments

Comment: Digitimit, I do not want to pass the Request class from the controllers, the Geolocation class or it's associated methods itself must resolve the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to inject `Request` in Geolocation constructor like so:

```
namespace App\Libraries;

use Location;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GeoLocation
{   

   public function __construct(Request $request){
       $this->request = $request;
   }

    public function getLocationByIP($ip = null)
    {
        // If IP address is set
        if ($ip) {
            $location = Location::get($ip);
        } else {
            $location = Location::get();
        }

        // Get the location by city
        return $location->cityName;
    }

    public function getLocationByCoordinates($longitute, $latitude)
    {
        //
    }

    public function getLocation() //no need to inject here
    {
        // Check if the location is already set in the cookie
        if ($this->request->cookie('location')) {
            return $request->cookie('location');
        } else {
            $location = $this->getLocationByIP();

            // Set location in the cookie
            $request->cookie()->forever('location', $location);

            return $location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the request as argument in the index method, try this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    // here you forgot the parameter
    dd($this->location->getLocation($request));
    return view('pages.index');
}
```

Comment: good catch! that solved the problem. 
But I do not want to treat the dependencies as parameters that needs to be passed by the caller, in controller methods we can simply use this reflection feature without any problem right?

Comment: Yes, you can. Should not have any problem ;)

Comment: Well, for custom classes it works pretty good if you are registering them via [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container). It is a important concept to consider if you are developing with Laravel.